# JavaScript: How can i check if an array contains elements in common with a second array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

will be very simple question,

I have these two arrays:

```
var pcNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
var userNumbers = [1,2,7,8,9];
```

Pratically i have to find a way to create an alert who say "There are two elements in common, 1 and 2"

Tyia

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an array contains any element of another array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if an array contains a value of another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087791/how-can-i-check-if-an-array-contains-a-value-of-another-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: Here is a suitable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885569/5481110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution could be something like this:

```
const pcNumbers = [1,2,3,8,5];
const userNumbers = [1,2,7,8,9];
const newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < pcNumbers.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < userNumbers.length; j++) {
        if (pcNumbers[i] === userNumbers[j]) {
            newArr.push(pcNumbers[i])
        }
    }
};

console.log(`These are in common: ${newArr.join(', ')}`)
```

This will result in:

These are in common: 1, 2

Comment: what's the expected result for `[1,2,3,8,5] and [1,2,7,8,9,2]` @Emanuel Rista

Comment: This would be an edge case. You can always check if the number is in the array before you push it. For example: if (!(pcNumbers[i] in newArr)) { newArr.push(pcNumbers[i]) } - In this case, you will do a lot of looping, and a better solution would be to add the numbers to a JS object instead (hash table). That would make the lookup a faster, but would require a bit different code.

Comment: So I am just saying that this is the best efficient solution. :D

Answer (score 7):

You can filter one array by checking each item in another using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

```js
var pcNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
var userNumbers = [1,2,7,8,9];
var commonNumbers = pcNumbers.filter(i => userNumbers.includes(i));
console.log(commonNumbers);
```

Comment: btw, don't use `var`, use `let` instead.

Comment: @ʎzɐɹƆ do not use `let` if you are not re-assigning. Use `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is really simple question.

Go through the 1st array and check if each element appears in the 2nd array.

If so, push it to another array or just display it.

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const b = [2,4,5,7,11,15];

for(let i of a){
  if(b.includes(i)){
    console.log(i)
  }
}
--------- OR --------------
console.log(a.filter(e => b.includes(e)))
```